# How to Fetch Data from Firebase Realtime Database in React Native App

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I fetch data from Firebase Realtime Database using the below method?

My Realtime Database:

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useContext, } from 'react';
 import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator, FlatList, } from 'react-native';
    import {firebase} from '../config';
        export default function App() {
          const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
      const todoRef = firebase.firestore().collection('testing');
    useEffect(() => {
          todoRef.onSnapshot(
              querySnapshot => {
                  const users = []
                  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                      const { one, two, three, four
                
                      } = doc.data()
                      users.push({
                          id: doc.id,
                          one, two, three, four
                        
                      })
                  })
                  setUsers(users)
              }
          )
      }, [])
        
            return (
               <View style={{ backgroundColor: theme.viewOne, }}>
                            {isLoading ? <ActivityIndicator /> : (
                                <FlatList
                                ListHeaderComponent={
                                    <Image source={require('./AllImage/qq2.jpg')}
                                    style={{ width: "auto", height: 150, resizeMode: "cover", }} />
                                }
                                    data={data}
                                    keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
                                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
        
        
                                        <View style={styles.container}>
                                            <View style={styles.item}>
                                                <Text style={styles.mainText}>{item.one}</Text>
                                            </View>
        
                                            <View style={styles.item}>
                                                <Text style={styles.mainText}>{item.two}</Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                    )}
                                />
                            )}
                        </View>
            );
        };
```

Comment: Am I misunderstanding something here? The code in the snippet appears to have nothing at all to do with firebase, it's making a GET requests to fetch a `movies.json` file. What exactly is the issue? What are you trying to do? Can you edit your post to include a more representative [mcve]?

Comment: Hi Drew, I updated the code please check, I used Firestore data in the above code but now I want to fetch Firebase Realtime data

Comment: Ok, thanks for updating. I'll say that what you have appears to not have any overt issues. Is something not working as expected? What do you need help with?

Comment: I want to fetch data to my react native app from Firebase Realtime Database not from firestore database

Answer (score 1):

Rahul for react-native you can implement it like [this](https://rnfirebase.io/database/usage) instead of using async-await.
You need to connect your app to database like this -

```
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/database';

const reference = firebase
  .app()
  .database('https://<databaseName>.<region>.firebasedatabase.app/')
  .ref('/users/123');
```

Then you can perform read-write transactions like this -

```
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

database()
  .ref('/users/123')
  .once('value')
  .then(snapshot => {
    console.log('User data: ', snapshot.val());
  });
```

The article has a detailed implementation and you can choose to persist data easily as well. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Bhishak, thank you for your valuable answer, could you please check the code i just updated it. I was using Firestore database but now I want to use Firebase Realtime database, what should I need to change in the code?

Comment: The document I shared above is for real-time database implementation. From the useEffect() connect and fetch like mentioned above then setUsers().